# Specify a particular database query from command line with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, ddev

I would like to facilitate opening a database UI for development projects (usually docker containers, bound to arbitrary ports on the host machine) by a generic command.

I wonder if it is possible to open MySQL Workbench and let it connect automatically from the command line.

Similar to giving connection parameters with the `mysql` console:

```shell
mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=$port --user=db --password=db db
```

I haven't found that specifically [in the supported arguments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-command-line-options.html), so either it is hidden or maybe possible with any of the other options?

EDIT:
Probably the way is to generate a file to pass to `--query` dynamically?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've seen that already. How would my command look like to open a DB on port localhost:49155?

Comment: Well I dont know, I never tried it, but if I wanted to, I would do just that. Try something and if it does not work, read the manual again, and try something else. Bit like developing really, try try until yo succeed

Comment: Cant find a way to pass the password, so all this may be in vain

Comment: How did you set the port generically? Have you generated the query file dynamically?

Comment: `[64bit] MySQL5.7.28` is the name of a connection that exists already in my WorkBench. I use WAMPServer so I have many versions of MySQL and mariaDB that I could be using so I have amny canned connections in WorkBench

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the format for [the mysqlworkbench `--query` parameter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-command-line-options.html):

`--query="$user:$password@$host:$port"`

This feature already exists as an example in [ddev](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) - look in the `~/.ddev/commands/host/mysqlworkbench.example` file. (See on [github](https://github.com/drud/ddev/blob/master/pkg/ddevapp/global_dotddev_assets/commands/host/mysqlworkbench.example)).

For ddev, the query is set up as `query="root:root@127.0.0.1:${DDEV_HOST_DB_PORT}"`, which uses the root/root credentials, accesses the 'db' container via localhost on the port provided by ddev at $DDEV_HOST_DB_PORT.